# How can I update and insert value on my Foreign Key Column?

Tags: c#, oop

*I want to insert and update my table. My query statement is only indicate primary key, item name, description, price and so on.. The problem is I have another column which is the FOREIGN KEY. When I try to insert values to my item database table the error is occurred. It said that the column count doesn't match value count at row 1. And also how can I update the table if I have a column of FOREIGN KEY?*

```
class Item
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Stocks { get; set; }

        public int GenerateID()
        {
            int newID = 0;
            Connection connection = new Connection();
            string sql = "SELECT ItemID FROM tbl_Item ORDER BY ItemID DESC Limit 1";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                newID = dr.GetInt32("ItemID");
            }
            conn.Close();
            newID++;
            return newID;
        }

        public void UpdateRecord()
        {
            try
            {
                Connection connection = new Connection();
                string sql = "UPDATE Item SET ItemName=@itemName, Description=@desc, Price=@price, Stocks=@stocks WHERE ItemID=@itemId";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemId", ItemID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemName", ItemName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stocks", Stocks);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully", "Update Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + e, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        public void InsertRecord()
        {
            Connection connection = new Connection();
            try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Account VALUES(@itemId, @itemName, @desc, @price, @stocks)";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemId", ItemID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemName", ItemName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stocks", Stocks);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully", "Update Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
//for button ADD
private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Item item = new Item();

            item.ItemID = item.GenerateID();
            item.ItemName = txtINameItem.Text;
            item.Description = txtDescriptionItem.Text;
            item.Price = txtPriceItem.Text;
            item.Stocks = textStocksItem.Text;

            item.InsertRecord();
        }
```

Comment: When you write an Insert statement without specifying the columns that receives your values it is assumed that you provide values for all columns. What is the schema of your table tbl_Account? Also if you have a FK in this table is required to provide a value matching the key of the external table in the relationship

Comment: if you are using Insert into without specifying column names, you need to include data for all columns in table. You said that you got another column with foreign key, so you need to include it into your insert. Or specify columns in insert.

Comment: By the way, in he update code you use a table named _Item_ while in the insert code you have _tbl_Account_

Comment: do I need to create another generateID for foreign key? I put wrong table name that is tbl_Item not tbl_Account

Comment: and also do I need to declare a property for my FOREIGN KEY for example  public int ForeignID { get; set; }

Comment: Can you explain what is the relationship between the _tbl_Item_ and the 'other' table? If a record inside _tbl_Item_ is in some kind of relationship with another table you should provide the _link_ (the FK column) that connects the _tbl_item_ to the other table. To understand your problem we need to understand the relationship between these tables.

Comment: Ok. tbl_Account and tbl_Item is one-to-many relationship. When I insert value to the tbl_Item I want to insert the userID value as my foreign key column. It defends who is the user

Comment: Just a heads up, you should close db connection withing Finally block instead.

Comment: `//like this finally { conn.Close() }`

Comment: *tbl_Account and tbl_Item is one-to-many relationship* - is that a userID can have multiple items, or in reverse? Are you want somewhat like "cascade update" when inserting `tbl_Item`?

Comment: userID can have multiple items. I don't know what is cascade update

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL code is wrong. You must pass valid Foreign Key value while inserting the record. Valid Foreign Key value is the value already existing in the Parent Table OR NULL. However, setting NULL to Foreign Key column is based on how you have created the Foreign Key on the Child Table.

Try below code replacing @fkValue & FkValue with correct Foreign Key column order in the Child Table and value:

```
                string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Account VALUES(@itemId, @fkValue, @itemName, @desc, @price, @stocks)";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemId", ItemID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fkValue", FkValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemName", ItemName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stocks", Stocks);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

Hope this helps!